# BroadcastReceiver ACTION_SETTINGS. Não intercepta

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Boa noite a todos. Gostaria que minha aplicação fosse chamada quando o usuário clicasse em "Configurações" no aparelho dele.

Dessa forma então tentei utilizar um *BroadcastReceiver* para interceptar o `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS` e colocar minha aplicação como padrão.

Estou suando a camisa, criei uma app com:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Essa app funciona corretamente, ela invoca o configurador do Android. Acontece que eu gostaria que o meu broadcast fosse reconhecido, e ao chamar essa activity o Android exibisse minha aplicação para o usuário selecionar ela ou o configurador.

Fiz então o broadcast:

```
<receiver android:name=".BlockConfig">
   <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Mas quando chamo o Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS, ela abre diretamente no configurador.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz onde estou errando?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Julgo que está a enfrentar o mesmo problema/confusão expressa nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329223/2556111), cuja [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329239/2556111) é simples:

> You cannot "intercept" `startActivity()` calls using a *BroadcastReceiver*. A *BroadcastReceiver* receives broadcasts, not `startActivity()` calls.

> Você não pode "interceptar" chamadas via `startActivity()` usando um *BroadcastReceiver*. O *BroadcastReceiver* recebe transmissões, não chamadas via `startActivity()`.

Ou seja, `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);` irá lançar uma *Activity* e não um *BroadcastReceiver*

O que pode tentar(não testei) é, no AndroidManifest.xml, adicionar

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

ao `<intent-filter>` da *Activity* que quer que seja lançada.

Comment: Olá Ramaral. Agradeço a resposta, mas ocorre inicialmente meus testes eram invocando um Broadcast corretamente

**sendBroadcast(new Intent("NOME DO BROADCAST"));**

O problema não é invocar o broadcast, consigo tanto o meu quanto os nativos do Android (como o caso do android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)

O problema e que não consigo fazer o Android identificar que minha aplicação também possui um broadcast desse, e exibir pro usuario escolher com qual aplicação abrir esta chamada (a minha ou o configurador padrão do android)

Comment: Já tentou fazer aquilo que eu sugeri na resposta?